# I can't add foreign key:There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    [ID1] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [Desc] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT [PK_VMO_FunzioniAutorizzabiliL1] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID1)
    WITH 
    (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    [ID2] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [IDRow] int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID2] ASC,
    [IDRow] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE T3
(
    [USER] [nvarchar] (25) NOT NULL
    [ID3] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [IDRow] int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [USER] ASC,
    [ID3] ASC,
    [IDRow] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In another query I created the constraints:

With this no problems

```
ALTER TABLE [T2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_T2_T1_ID2] FOREIGN KEY(ID2)
REFERENCES [T1] (ID1)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE [T2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_T2_T1_ID2];
```

With these others I received the error in question:

```
ALTER TABLE [T3]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_T3_T2_ID3] FOREIGN KEY(ID3)
REFERENCES [T2] (ID2)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE [T3] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_T3_T2_ID3];

ALTER TABLE [T3]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_T3_T2_IDRow] FOREIGN KEY(IDRow)
REFERENCES [T2] (IDRow)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE [T3] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_T3_T2_IDRow];
```

I wouldn't want the problem to be that the key of T2 used as foreign key of the T3 table is a foreign key of the T1 table

Comment: [T2] (ID2) should be PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index. [T2] (IDRow) the same. Probably [T1] (ID1) already it is. When you reference to a PRIMARY KEY, you must reference to all the fields within this PRIMARY KEY, not only one of them.

Comment: The difference I see is that in T1 your primary key is only 1 attribute (ID1). While for other table it's 2 or 3 value. While when you try to create the constraint you just select "ID2" or "ID3" that are "only part of" primary keys.

Comment: What SQL is this? SQL Server? Please [edit] your post to tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, there are no keys you can bind that foreign key to.

In `T1`, you're creating a foreign key over a single column that references a primary key with a single column. That's okay.

But in `T2` (or `T3`), you're creating a foreign key over a single column, but there's no key on `T2` (or `T3`) that ensures `T2.ID2` (or `T3.ID3`) is unique.

The foreign key must reference a unique constraint or a primary key. If `T2.ID2` (or `T3.ID3`) is unique, you can just add a unique constraint. If not, the foreign key must cover the whole primary/unique key.

Comment: Adding that the referenced key can be a unique index in SQL Server, not just a primary key or unique constraint (albeit seldom done in practice).

Comment: For T3 I have another table in relation, I was wrong and in fact I had created two queries to create the constraints for the same table instead of a single one